# How to merge 2 arrays of objects keeping only the new objects and getting the properties of the old objects?

Tags: javascript

I know there are dozens of questions titles similar to this one, but I couldn't find the one that solved my problem.

The point is that I'm avoiding unnecessary queries to the Database. So when the query is made, only what is needed is consumed. I get the data and merge it with LocalStorage to save usage.

I created this example to make it easier to read and help future users:

```js
let usersDB = [
  { id: 1, name: 'John', age: 34 },
  { id: 2, name: 'Rose', age: 27 },
  { id: 3, name: 'Daniel', age: 40 },
]
const usersLS = [
  { id: 1, name: 'John', cars: ['BMW', 'Ferrari'] },
  { id: 2, name: 'Rose', cars: ['Tesla', 'Camaro'] },
  { id: 4, name: 'Ambrose', cars: ['Fiat'] },
]

/** Expected Result:
 * [
 *   {id: 1, name: 'John', cars: ['BMW', 'Ferrari']},
 *   {id: 2, name: 'Rose', cars: ['Tesla', 'Camaro']},
 *   {id: 3, name: 'Daniel'},
 * ]
 */
```

In the example above, `userDB` and `userLS` represent the Database and LocalStorage users, respectively.

Naturally, `userDB` is the most "updated", but `userLS` has a property "cars" which is not in the same table as the users in the database. So I need to update `userLS` using `userDB` as base, but without losing the "cars" property.

I know I could do a for...loop to iterate over users and within that, another for...loop to check if the id is the same and then generate a new array with the objects. However, I believe that there must be better ways to solve this problem.

---

#### Edit: What I have tried

```js
let newArr = [];

for (let userDB of usersDB) {
  for (let userLS of usersLS) {
    if (userDB.id === userLS.id) {
      userDB.cars = userLS.cars
      newArr.push(userDB);
    }
  }
}
usersDB = Object.assign([...usersDB], ...newArr)
```

The code above is the way I am using to solve this problem. Can you think of a more direct solution?

Comment: I edited my question to show the code I'm using and it's working. I just believe he can get better. I understand if you're having a bad day.

Comment: You can not compare two different  arrays with `===` . As for me having a bad day I don't know how you arrived at that idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Array.map()` on the usersDB array, then merge properties with any userLS found for any given user.

We'd use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to merge each item in the array(s):

```js
const usersDB = [
  { id: 1, name: 'John', age: 34 },
  { id: 2, name: 'Rose', age: 27 },
  { id: 3, name: 'Daniel', age: 40 },
]

const usersLS = [
  { id: 1, name: 'John', cars: ['BMW', 'Ferrari'] },
  { id: 2, name: 'Rose', cars: ['Tesla', 'Camaro'] },
  { id: 4, name: 'Ambrose', cars: ['Fiat'] },
]

const result = usersDB.map(( { age, ...userDB}, idx) => { 
    let userLS = usersLS.find(u => u.id === userDB.id);
    return { ...userLS, ...userDB};
}, {})

console.log('Result:', result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Amazing solution! Exactly what I was looking for. I just have one question: would it be wrong if I directly change the value of `userDB` instead of creating the `const result`? (assuming userDB was a variable)… I mean: `userDB = usersDB.map…`

Comment: That should work nicely I think!

Comment: Yeah man, it's working beautifully. Thank you for that. I just noticed: what is idx?

Answer (score 1):

`Array.map` will help

**Logic**

- Loop through `usersDB` array with `Array.map`
- Find the matching node from `usersLS` array comparing the id
- If the matching node found assign the `cars` property from that object to your return node from map function.

**Working Fiddle**

```js
let usersDB = [
  { id: 1, name: 'John', age: 34 },
  { id: 2, name: 'Rose', age: 27 },
  { id: 3, name: 'Daniel', age: 40 },
]
const usersLS = [
  { id: 1, name: 'John', cars: ['BMW', 'Ferrari'] },
  { id: 2, name: 'Rose', cars: ['Tesla', 'Camaro'] },
  { id: 4, name: 'Ambrose', cars: ['Fiat'] },
];
const userConsolidated = usersDB.map((user) => {
  const usersLSnode = usersLS.find((item) => item.id === user.id);
  const { id, name } = user;
  const returnNode = { id, name };
  if (usersLSnode) returnNode.cars = usersLSnode.cars;
  return returnNode
});

console.log(userConsolidated);
```

Comment: Inside the property "cars" you are including the properties of array.

Comment: @Arnon You can simply access the `cars` node from that object and assign this to pushing object. Updated the answer.